# Difference between next() and nextLine() when we are in a loop

Tags: java, methods

I was working with array and i wanted to make a list that user can set a value for its length and then also user can add some String values duo to it's length that user set up.I wanted the program to show me the list that user entered to user (just practicing) and i found out a different use of `next()` and `nextLine()` that `nextLine`() method wouldn't work properly since i wanted to add as many String as i wanted to my Array.here is what i am thinking:

```
System.out.println("Welcome to addingCourse wizard :)");
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your course: ");
        int z = input.nextInt();
        String[] course = new String[z];

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length ; i++) {

            course[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Ok. Here is your list...");

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(course[i]);
        }
```

problem is `nextLine()` wouldn't allow us to add items as we wanted in array.for example if you want your list to be 100, it will allow you to just enter 99 items although `next()` method allow `course.length` items and print all items

Comment: why is that so ?

Comment: The first nextLine will read the new line char (pressing return/enter) after answering the first question. You could use nextLine() instead of nextInt() and then convert from String to int yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these lines

```
    int z = input.nextInt();
    String[] course = new String[z];

    for (int i = 0; i < course.length ; i++) {

        course[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Whenever you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, this creates a new line **/n** character. As soon as you read your integer on the first line, nextInt isnt consuming said char. Take a good look at the output after your lines are being printed, the first line is an empty line.

To consume this new line, add another nextLine() right after you finish reading your int.

```
int z = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); //Consumes the new line character
```